# How to include Android.mk in another makefile

Tags: makefile, android-ndk

I have a problem including another Android.mk and build the dependent shared library.

Makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

MY_CORE_PATH := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE     := Phone
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := phone.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libCore

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)    
include $(MY_CORE_PATH)/Android.mk
```

When I compile this I get an error,

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'libCore.so' needed by 'libPhone.so'. Stop.
```

The libCore.so however builds without any issues but this makefile is not able to refer that correctly. Please provide any suggestions on how to resolve this.

NDK and Android version: android-ndk-r6, API level 9 building for Android ICS.

I am currently able to resolve by making the following changes.

```
# Modified Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_CORE_PATH := $(abspath $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..)

# libCore
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Core
include $(MY_CORE_PATH)/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE     := Phone
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := phone.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += libCore

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for my compile error. It is because the LOCAL_MODULE name is not correctly provided in the other makefile. Below are the changes done,

[1] In the Android.mk that was building libCore.so, module name was mentioned as,

```
LOCAL_MODULE := Core
```

instead of

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libCore
```

[2] The last two statements are interchanged; Makefile is first included and then the library is built.

My understanding was that 'lib' is optional in the module name. I didn't doubt this because it was building fine within NDK, problem seen when it is built as part of Android source tree.